# How to attach file or files via sending email from NLog mail target?

Tags: nlog

I am working with NLog latest versions. Is it possible to attach a file via sending email?
I searched online but didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The official targets doesn't have support for attachments. I'm not aware of one that support this.

You could vote for this [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3908), or send a pull request :)